# How can I prevent my bluetooth headset from preempting the internal mic on connection?

Tags: audio

How can I prevent my bluetooth headset from preempting the internal mic on connection?

Every time I connect my headset I am forced to go into sound preferences to set the mic back to the internal microphone.

macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score -1):

You must go to `System Preferences > Bluetooth`, select the headset device and click the `X` on the right side to remove it. When you need to use the headset again, it will need re-pairing. (Screenshot below shows my Apple Trackpad, for which new batteries are imminently needed!)

[image]

Comment: My problem is arising when I make a connection. I want to be able to use them as the output and not the input.

Comment: I'm not sure you can separate the two functions in Bluetooth. I do not have such a device, so I cannot test myself. Sorry.